# mvc contrib pager question - AsPagination

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I might be wrong but is the AsPagination method not very inefficient as it sucks all the data from a repository first to initialise TotalItems etc.? So paging is not used to make the data access more efficient.

I have not found any examples which use a repository and 'true' paging (i.e. uses TOP etc. in the atcual SQL). How do I use the Pager if I have a repository method with this signature:

IList GetData(int? page, out int TotalItems)

Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`CustomPagination<T>`](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Project/MVC-Contrib/1.0.0.916/Release/All/MvcContrib/MvcContrib/Pagination/CustomPagination.cs) class which is part of MVCContrib like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page)
{
    int totalItems;
    int pageSize = 10;
    var data = Repository.GetData(page, out totalItems);
    var paginatedData = new CustomPagination<Bla>(
        data, page, pageSize, totalItems
    );
    return View(paginatedData);
}
```

and inside your view:

```
<%= Html.Pager(Model) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be misdirected with your assumptions on the paging efficiency?  Try taking a look at the executing sql in profiler - it executes two sql statements - one to retrieve the count and one to select the top 10.  Below is the results of the executed sql from profiler -

This sql retrieves gets the count - used by the pager:

```
SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
   COUNT(1) AS [A1]
   FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
)
AS [GroupBy1]
```

While the following is the sql used to retrieve the data:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName],
...
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], ..., row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Company] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 20
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Company] ASC
```

Notice the TOP(10), row_number() over, and where ... > 20 statements in the second sql script? Does that help clarify?

Comment: I guess it depends on how your data access works. But I have seen many examples like this: repository.GetAll().AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10); So what I was trying to say is that they get all the data and then slice/page which is higly inefficient. However, using the custompagination I can easily establish a dependency (in terms of page number).

Comment: Ah, I see Christian.  When I pull data from a database, I use a ViewModel and a ViewModel Builder that abstracts my repositories; however, within the abstraction, my repository return an IQueryable<T>,  and the AsPagination takes care of the rest.  E.g. _customerListViewModelBuilder.Build().Customers.OrderBy(sort.Column, sort.Direction).AsPagination(
                    page ?? 1, size ?? 10);  - Customers is a property abstracted from my repository - Customers = _customerRepository.Queryable().  I wish you could add code snippet formatting in comments... Hope that helps...

Comment: @Dan you are correct. It all depends on what kind of interface you feed the AsPagination() method. if it is an IEnumerable<T>, the paging will be done in memory (DB backend will retriebe all rows); if it is an IQueryable<T>, the paging will be handled by the back-end (i.e. generated T-SQL will include a TOP expression). If you want to force the back-end paging you simpy do `.AsQueryable().AsPagination(page ?? 1)`